# Selling packages: which product type should I use

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-1.9, configurable-product, bundled-product

I would be really grateful for any advice about how to model my product packages within Magento.  Below are my 4 requirements:

1. I would like to sell packages which consist of several products.
2. I would like the stock levels of the constituent products to be recorded and managed within Magento.
3. I would like to set the base price of the packages as a whole, not have it calculated as the sum of the constituent products.
4. Some consituent products will be configurable products, which can change the price of the package depending on selection.

Currently I have experimented with "Bundled" product types for the packages. The problem with this, is that configurable products (4. above) can only change the price if I set the Bundled product to be dynamic price rather than fixed, which breaks my #3 requirement.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: That looks like a product type you will have to create that merges the features you want of bundled products, configurable products, and custom attributes I'd guess.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you have 3 Options

1.-Try if you can generate a set with good bundle configuration [here to try it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751276/creating-magento-bundled-or-group-products-with-configurable-products)

2.-Change Original bundle options to create product with configurable product, and change view template

3.- Use a Custom Product View Block. that load multiple simple and configurable product , and Create a custom Ajax "Add to Cart" controller to add products